# FFMPEG - subtitles not showing for the full duration of video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I could not archive the following:

1. Have images loaded from a textfile to create a slideshow.
2. Have a background music with volume control.
3. Have my voice.mp3 over the bg music.
4. Have subtitles in the ass format.
5. Have a text shown with drawtext in the full duration of video.
6. in only one command, if possible.

The command I tryed is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i images.txt -i bg_music.m4a -i voice.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile='fonte.TTF':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:text='Imagens da internet':x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10,[0]overlay=10:10,ass=subtitles.txt[out],[1]volume=0.3[a1];[2]volume=2[a2];[a1][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest[aud]" -map "[out]" -map "[aud]":a -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -c:s mov_text -r 30 -y out.mp4
```

It works but not for subtitles that are showing only after the first image of th slideshow appears.

the content of images.txt is:

```
file 'image1.png'
duration 20
file 'image2.png'
duration 5
file 'image3.png'
duration 5
```

the content of subtitles.txt is

```
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.00,0:00:06.00,Default,,0,0,0,,Subscribe!
Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.00,0:00:16.00,Default2,,0,0,0,,Like!
Dialogue: 0,0:00:17.00,0:00:26.00,Default,,0,0,0,,Share!
```

The problem is that only the "Share!" text is shown.